# Does Fortran make copies of array sections passed to function/subroutine?

Tags: c++, arrays, fortran

When passing sections of arrays to subroutines in Fortran, e.g. `f(a, b, c(2:5,4:6))` (all of them 2D arrays), does the program first make a temporary copy of `c`, and then pass it to the subroutine (as reference, pointer, etc), or is the whole thing dynamically handled?

I am trying to convert some Fortran code to C++, and I see calls to subroutines that have sections of arrays passed as arguments. To my knowledge, C++ doesn't allow this so I tried to circumvent this in C++ like this (`mat2d = std::vector<std::vector<T>>`):

```
f(mat2d &a, mat2d &b, mat2d *a, int rows, int rows, int offsetx, int offsety) {...}
```

and calling as:

```
f(a, b, c.data(), ...)
```

This works but it requires the size(s), and also offsets for the cases where I want to make a generic matrix multiplication (for example). So, if Fortran first makes a copy of `c(2:5,4:6)` to (say) a `temp(4,3)` array, then I can mimic that in C++: simply make a copy to a temporary, and then pass a reference of that temporary to the function, without rows/columns/offsets. But if not... I wouldn't mind hearing other people's thoughts.

---

Example subroutine:

```
subroutine f(A, B, C)
  implicit none
  real(kind(1d0)) :: A(2,2), B(2,2), C(2,2)
  C = A*B
  return
end f
```

---

If my words are bad, maybe a picture with the real code will do? The arrays are `auxfour(4,4)`, `aux44(4,4)`, and `Gv(2,2)`.

[image: code]

And here is a call, with `auxp(5)` and the same `Gv`:

[image: code2]

Full subroutine. Picture, not words.

[image: sub]

Comment: That really depends on the Fortran subroutine (which you do not show). Fortran can also pass array descriptors for non-contiguous arrays.

Comment: @VladimirF I've added some bogus, similar example to what I see in the Fortran code. If not, consider the builtin `matmul()`, which is also of interest (for me). I also have something like `x(1:2,:)=matmul(y,z(1:2,:))`. But I'm interested for any case where a slice of array is passed on: is that a copy, or not?

Comment: Are at least the definitions in the subroutine correct? You cannot just make *any* subroutine, you need to show *your* subroutine. It does depend. Search for explicit shape, assumed size, assumed shape, explicit interface and so on. The passing mechanism does depend on that.

Comment: I wonder why you need to replicate the passing mechanism anyway, shouldn't you rathersearch foor what will be best to use for C++?

Comment: First of: `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` is a really bad way of defining a matrix in C++. Second: what is your real question? Are you trying to set up a function in C++ that you can call from Fortran or are you setting up a function in Fortran that you can call from C++, or what is the real question here? The title is extremely interesting but seems totaly unrelated to the question.

Comment: @VladimirF I know what you mean, that example does, largely, what one of the subroutines does: it takes 3 matrices, two of them serve for calculations for the 3rd one, which is the output (C). But, as I said in the previous comment, if that is not satisfactory, then consider the builtin `matmul()`, which can take a section of an array as argument.

Comment: @kvantour It's the first phrase: when you have for example `f(a(1:3,:))`, is `a` first copied to a temporay location, or is it passed directly? I want to emulate that section of an array in a C++ function. I want to be able to pass a part of an array,be it `vector<vector>`, or simply NxN size `vector`.

Comment: We do not need the code inside, but we DO NEED to see how the arguments look like. I do not believe they are a(2,2), that is really bogus. We need to see how *exactly* are they arguments you want to pass the array to declared. We do not care what you do inside. Matmul or whatever else, it does not matter.

Comment: @VladimirF Maybe a picture says a thousand words? I've updated the question to include a pic with a line of the original code. It looks very similar to what I've descrived in the first phrase.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  gfortran has an option that tells you when a temporary array is created.

Comment: @steve I use gfortran. What option is that? I think I found it, `-fcheck-array-temporaries`.

Comment: But I asked you for the *definitions*. We really do not need any call to matmul or to anything else. But we need to know how the arguments/parameters are defined *inside* the subroutine `f`. I readdly do not beleive they are `real(kind(1d0)) :: A(2,2), B(2,2), C(2,2)`.

Comment: It's described in the documentation that comes with the compiler.  It has the obvious name -Warray-temporaries.

Comment: @VladimirF I am not lying. I've added another picture of the actual code. And, just to be sure, I made a simple test with the bogus code I've posted, the one you said `A(2,2)` can't be. [It works.](https://www.ideone.com/cUjFDm)

Comment: @steve I think it does make a temporary copy, because I made a simple [test](https://www.ideone.com/qm2Dm6) and compiled it with `-fcheck-array-temporaries`, and it says there's a temporary at the first call, but not at the second. If you make this an answer, I'll mark it down. This is one of the two answers I was expecting (either it does or it doesn't make a copy, with proof).

Comment: Off to bed but the short answer is there is no answer to your initial question as the Fortran standard doesn't say whether a copy need be made or not - it only says what the result should be. This is usual for Fortran, a compiler is free to implement it anyway it wants so long as the result is correct. Thus one compiler could make a copy, another might not. Different versions of the same compiler might do different things. You can only rely on what the result is, not how getting to that result is implemented.

Comment: @IanBush I see, then if, as the comment just above yours, I find that it does make a copy, that should only be because gfortran does it, so it's an unreliable answer for other compilers, no?

Comment: Correct, another compiler, or even a different version of gfortran may behave differently. The compiler is even free to vary how it does it within the same program, and for different calls to the same routine

Comment: @IanBush I see, thank you for this. I am really not sure if either you, or steve, post an answer, which one should I choose. But I suppose yours, as you state that it *could* be, *unless*..., while steve said to simply verify.

Comment: Intel compiler has a runtime flag to tell you when temp arrays are created for arguments. For example with `SUM(2.0D0*A)`.

Comment: @ja72 I don't use Intel compiler, but I suppose it's similar to g++'s mentioned somewhere in the comments above. But, yes, that was very useful, and (partially) lead to the conclusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true that the Fortran standard does not specify the details of the passing mechanism. However, because the compilers are trying to be efficient, we can say a lot about what normally happens in practice.

The Fortran standard does not specify that arguments are passed by reference, but the rules efectively require it. However, it could always be a reference to temporary copy. The reference normally means just the memory address (pointer) of the first element. That enables the perfectly valid usage when one passes only one element and references the whole array inside the subroutine/function.

In some cases the temporary copy is virtually unavoidable.

Let's consider

```
real :: a(10,10)

call f(a(2:5,4:6))
```

then if `f` is

```
subroutine f(c)
  real :: c(3,3)
```

then there is very little the compiler can do, the temporary copy is virtually guaranteed. The same holds for

```
subroutine f(c)
  real :: c(3,*)
```

However, for assumed shape array

```
subroutine f(c)
  real :: c(:,:)
```

that is not the case. These arguments are passed using an array descriptor and can be non-contiguous and you normally won't see temporary copies for them.

Finally, if the first dimension is complete:

```
real :: a(2:5,10)

call f(a(:,4:6))
```

the copy is not necessary either as the subarray is contiguous in memory.

---

Even when a temporary is not necessary, the compiler could always make it, nothing is guaranteed. But it is not very likely in practise. Compilers try to be efficient.